# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string mssql sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, datetime, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use Sequelize and node js to connect to a MS Sql server database and i have the following error when i try to test the post route in Postman:
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."
The field in the database has the datetime type and i don't know how to solve the conversion problem.

Here's the code where i'm trying to do the conversion:

```
async function createFeedback(UserId,feedback) {
    try{
        //eroare la data->trebuie rezolvata
        return await Feedback.create({
            Mesaj: feedback.Mesaj,
            Recenzie: feedback.Recenzie,
            DataFeedback:Date.parse(feedback.DataFeedback),
            UserId: UserId
  });

}
catch(e){
  return e.message;
}


}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

The Feedback entity is defined like this:

```
import db from '../dbConfig.js';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const Feedback = db.define("Feedback", {
    FeedbackId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    Mesaj: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    Recenzie: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    DataFeedback: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE, 
        allowNull: false  

       
    },
    UserId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }

})
export default Feedback;
```

Comment: And the value you are trying to convert is?

Comment: This is the json i added in the body{
"Mesaj":"ceva",
"Recenzie":"Some test",
"DataFeedback":"04 Dec 2020 00:12:00 GMT",
"UserId":5
}

Comment: Pass your datetime value as '20201204 00:12:00' or use convert with the appropriate style

Comment: @sepupic i tried passing it like you said, nothing changed

Comment: >>>The field in the database has the datetime type<<< If your column is datetime, my format is correct. Are your sure it's datetime?

Comment: Another valid format for datetime can be ''2020-12-04T00:12:00.000'

Comment: @sepupic I tried inserting it manually and it appears that this is the format in the database:  2020-01-04 22:21:01.000

Comment: There is no "format in database". It appears to you according to your login language. I gave you 2 language independant formats to pass datetime value as a string

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code of `Feedback.init()`? How is it defining the `DataFeedback` field with Sequelize?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I updated the code

Answer (score 4):

This is formating [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7879)  of Sequelize for MSSQL database. Sequelize by putting the extra value '+00:00' that is not accepted by the MSSQL.

Need to [override](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7879#issuecomment-329971730) timezone formatting for MSSQL

```
Sequelize.DATE.prototype._stringify = function _stringify(date, options) {
  date = this._applyTimezone(date, options);
  // Z here means current timezone, _not_ UTC
  // return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS Z');
  return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
};
```

Comment: Tested successfully with mssql 9.0.1 and sequelize 6.25.6.

`import {  DATE } from 'sequelize';

DATE.prototype._stringify = function _stringify(date: any, options: any) {
      date = this._applyTimezone(date, options);
      return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
    };
`

Comment: Ugh. I thought the whole idea of using Sequelize was to NOT have to deal with these idiosyncracies.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set your locale (according to your region):

```
const moment = require('moment')
require('moment/locale/fa')
moment.locale('fa');
```

Then in your `createFeedback` function, you'll have:

```
return await Feedback.create({
            Mesaj: feedback.Mesaj,
            Recenzie: feedback.Recenzie,
            DataFeedback: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'),
            UserId: UserId
  });
```

I tested the above code successfully. Hope this helped :)